Gradle - Service Under Maintenance
When building an android project that use gradle, I failed to fetch some dependencies.
After searching for a while, I found gradle is Under Maintenance:

You can check the status at: https://status.gradle.com/
Does this means gradle can't be used now?
What can I do, just wait for it to recover?
How can a general tool get into such a status. I never see this happen to maven.

In my experience there is nothing to do, just wait until the maintenance is finish all services are operational the only one under maintenance at the moment is DPE University (dpeuniversity-develocity.gradle.com) normally wont take long then the status will be changed.

It's still Under Maintenance after 12 hours.

Now it becomes All Systems Operational.
